# Below is java script code, how can this be implemented in dart, it seems like < operator does't work for strings in Dart

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

var user1 = "Frank"; // UID of user 1
var user2 = "Eusthace"; // UID of user 2

var roomName = 'chat_'+(user1<user2 ? user1+'*'+user2 : user2+'*'+user1);

console.log(user1+', '+user2+' => '+ roomName);

user1 = "Eusthace";
user2 = "Frank";

var roomName = 'chat_'+(user1<user2 ? user1+'*'+user2 : user2+'*'+user1);

console.log(user1+', '+user2+' => '+ roomName);

Comment: The JS Less-Than documentation says that the values are first converted to primitives, so have you tried that? [MDN Less Than](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than)

Comment: I want the same code in dart, but dart does't accept >< operators for Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var roomName = 'chat_'+(user1<user2 ? user1+''+user2 : user2+''+user1);`

could be translated to

`var roomName = 'chat${user1.compareTo(user2) < 0 ? '$user1$user2' : '$user2$user1'}';`

It could be that I am wrong with the `<`... If yes, `>` is correct. :-)

Okay, short explanation: x.compareTo(y) is a sorting method on many classes (including String). It returns -1 if x should be sorted before y, +1 if it should be sorted after y, and 0 if both are usually ranked equally.

Strings are sorted alphabetically (not sure about special characters like German umlauts though), DateTime objects are sorted as "earlier before later", and so on. In your own classes, you are free to define your own sorting logic (and it makes sense to also use a compareTo method for it).

Comment: Thanks man! saved me an hour